# One Definition Rule (ODR) when implementing stack in multiple classes

Tags: c++, stack, one-definition-rule

Can't seem to get a simple stack implementation working. I'm simply trying to get two different classes (class B & class C) to be able to push and print element in the **same** stack being managed by a third class (class A).

A.cpp

```
#include "A.h"
void A::pop() {}
void A::push() {}
void A::print() {}  // prints last pushed elements
```

A.h

```
#include < iostream >
  class A 
  {
    public:
    void pop();
    void push();
    void print();
  }
```

B.cpp

```
#include "B.h"
#include "A.h"

A a;

void B::Text() { a.push(); }
void B::Background() { a.print(); }  // works!
```

C.cpp

```
#include "C.h"
#include "A.h"

A _a; // why doesn't A a work? because ODR?
void B::Text() { _a.push(); }
void B::Background() { _a.print(); } // doesn't work! breakpoint shows empty stack!
```

I think I'm breaking the One Definition Rule. Am I right?

Comment: it doesn't if in C.pp I have defined class A as "A a" instead of "A _a".  Secondly, do you know why my stack is empty in class B when I'm trying to access it even though I just pushed an element in that class.

Comment: You're basically talking about a global variable.  All the usual caveats apply (summary: don't do this!!).  But if you simply *must* do this, then decide which cpp file should be the canonical "owner" of `a`, define it there, and then put `extern A a` in the header file.

Comment: @Daqs Just for accuracy: _I have defined class A as "A a"_  — You have defined an _object_ `a` of class `A`.

Comment: @bolov: That is a bold statement considering that many violations of the ODR need not be diagnosed... for example a.cpp: `inline int f() { return 1; }` and b.cpp: `inline int f() { return 2; }`; linking both together is a violation of the ODR, but chances are that your linker won't diagnose them.

Comment: @DavidRodríguez-dribeas ty, I spoke without thinking more about it. I'll delete my comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, each variable must be defined exactly once.
Use `extern A a` in C.cpp.

Comment: This solved the problem. In class B, I declared A a as extern and I was able to access the stack without a problem in class C. Thanks! I will select this as the answer as soon as I'm allowed to.

Comment: @Daqs That's a terrible design though. You shouldn't be relying on global variables.

Comment: @juanchopanza why not? how about give a constructive criticism?

Comment: @Daqs Just look it up. And think what can happen if you rely on something that can be modified *everywhere*.

Comment: @juanchopanza As Oliver Charlesworth already mentioned using global variables is considered [evil](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/148108/why-is-global-state-so-evil).

Comment: @Serikov You don't have to tell *me* that :-)

Answer (score 1):

By creating `A a` in B.cpp and `A a` in C.cpp you actually have 2 different objects and they won't point to the same stack.

An alternative to achieve the same would be to make `A` as singleton object.